# Is Low Search right for this?

Tags: low-search, filter

I have two forms on a site I'm developing, one form I need to be able to filter by categories and sub-categories, the other I need to filter by keyword, File Type (PDF, EXE) and list them based on their category.

Is Low Search right for this?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on **what** you're filtering. [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) will filter **channel entries**.

- Use the [Categories filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories) to filter by (sub)categories;
- You can use the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords) in conjunction with the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search) to filter by keywords and the File Type, *if* the file type is stored in a dedicated channel field.

Whether you can *“list them based on their category”* depends on what you mean by that, exactly. If you can generate the output using the native `channel:entries` tag, then you can also output it using [the Results tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#results-tag).